# Windows 10, cmd start with & in the command path

Tags: windows, command-line, command-line-arguments, escape-characters

I'm now using OneDrive for work. This has caused me some problems with a specific command that I have pined. The OneDrive path now contains spaces dashes and an ampersand.

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c "START /b /D C:\Users\NJC\OneDrive - A&B Services, LLC\Documents\emacs-26.1\bin\runemacs.exe"
```

If I click on the pinned icon, I get:

```
Windows cannot find '-'. Make sire you typed the name correctly, and then try again.
```

So far I've tried various combinations of caret and char, adding ^" around the command path and a mix of other things but nothing works.

I can not rename the path and I do not have admin on this machine. So I am stuck with the path.

Any suggestion on fixing the quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try my updated answer:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c START "" "\\?\C:\Users\NJC\OneDrive - A&B Services, LLC\Documents\emacs-26.1\bin\runemacs.exe" /b /d
```

Since Windows found a ampersand it thinks you want to execute more than 1 command, but if you use \\?\ in the beginning of the path it ignores path phrasing.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it starts a new command shell. The problem here is that the "Start ..." is the command to pass to cmd.exe. That's why it's quoted.

Comment: Please try the updated answer....

Comment: I tried the updated answer with no luck, Where did you find the information about the \?\ ?

Comment: I tested the start command myself by including a "&" in the target and it worked for me, strange...I got it here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file

Comment: I missed the "" it worked!! Oh for emacs move the /b before the command string. Otherwise it thinks it's an option for emacs.